# How to remove proxy using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, proxy

I am opening a site using selenium proxy setting in chrome options. From that site, when i click a PAYMENT button it takes me to another site. I need to remove proxy before clicking PAYMENT button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `setNoProxy("")`. You have to be careful while using capabilities with it. Some time people use `setProxyByServer` JSON object for chrome or firefox but in my experience it works only for IE. 
Here is a sample:

```
Proxy proxy = startProxy();
proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.MANUAL); 
proxy.setNoProxy("");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
ChromeOptions opt= new ChromeOptions();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, opt);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",*ChromeDriverPath*);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Hope this will resolve your issue!